# Checking for any folder in a zip file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I need to write a code which unzips files and should skip a zip file if it detects that there is a folder(any) contained inside it.

I cant find help anywhere i need someone to point me in the right direction 
i can search for the contents inside the zip file using the code below.

```
dir_name = 'C:\\Users\Desktop\Python'
extension = ".zip"

os.chdir(dir_name)  # change directory from working dir to dir with files

for item in os.listdir(dir_name):  # loop through items in dir

    if item.endswith(extension):  # check for ".zip" extension
        file_name = os.path.abspath(item)  # get full path of files
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)  # create zipfile object
        print (zip_ref.namelist())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are >= 3.6 you can use [ZipInfo.is_dir()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.is_dir)

Something like below:

```py
dir_name = "/desired/path"
extension = ".zip"

os.chdir(dir_name)  # change directory from working dir to dir with files
for item in os.listdir(dir_name):  # loop through items in dir
    print('item is ', item)
    if not item.endswith(extension):
        continue
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.abspath(item)) as file:
        print('file to check is ', file)
        has_folder = any([a for a in file.infolist() if zipfile.ZipInfo.is_dir(a)])
        print(' has folder ', has_folder, ' file is ', item)
```